# Sonarcube using rspec not showing count of Unit Tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I'm using Sonarqube with RoR and RSpec as testing tools, successfully get coverage but not the count of Unit Tests as shown on the image below:

[image: Sonarqube report]

Please help

---

Configuration:

spec_helper.rb

```rb
if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  require 'simplecov'
  require 'simplecov-json'
  SimpleCov.formatter = SimpleCov::Formatter::JSONFormatter
  SimpleCov.start
end
```

sonar-project.properties

```
sonar.projectKey=myapp
sonar.sources=.
sonar.exclusions=**/vendor/**,**/coverage/**,**/assets/**
sonar.tests=app-code/spec
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*_spec.rb
sonar.test.exclusions=**/vendor/**
sonar.ruby.coverage.reportPaths=app-code/coverage/.resultset.json
sonar.ruby.coverage.framework=RSpec
```

Gemfile

```
  gem 'simplecov', '>= 0.17', '< 0.18'
  gem 'simplecov-json', '<= 0.2'
```

Comment: Did you find a way? It's a shame, I can see so many people having issues with Sonar/Ruby and no one cares

Comment: @Chocorean nope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `simplecov` is only used for coverage metrics. Unfortunately the is no native Ruby plugin that you can use to create a unit test count report, but you can use a `sonar.testExecutionReportPaths` parameter with generic report. I've used [this formater](https://github.com/otherguy/rspec-sonarqube-formatter) for it.

```rb
sonar.testExecutionReportPaths=./path-to-your/report.xml
```